# Clear input icon is not working properly in form which is having validations of angular js

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am trying to implement input clear icon in input textbox in my form . I am doing it through one directive. But its not working properly. Whenever I write something in input box , cross button doesn't show up untill and unless it is valid input for example when I type three characters in company name then only it shows up the cross button and not when characters are less than 3 or when the pattern is wrong.. I want that it should show everytime when I am writing any value in textbox. And when I click on cross button , it should clear the text and the required condition should be shown which is shown currently also when I am clicking cross. I am using below code for directive -

```
 .directive('inputClearNoMaterial', function(){
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: function (element, attrs) {
                var color = attrs.inputClearNoMaterial;
                var style = color ? "color:" + color + ";" : "";
                var action = attrs.ngModel + " = ''";
                element.after(
                    '<span class="animate-show"' +
                    'ng-show="' + attrs.ngModel + '" ng-click="' + action + '"' +
                    'style="position: absolute; margin: 3px 0px; cursor: pointer; ">' +
                    '<div style="' + style + '">x</div>' +
                    '</span>');
            }
        };
        });
```

Can anyone help me in this? Also cross button should be shown inside textbox as currently its outside the box. I have created a plunker here-
https://plnkr.co/edit/4sXB3S9HAuvszlZdimIU?p=preview

Comment: can you check your plunkr link, its not loading

Comment: Its loading but bit slowly, please try in firefox

Comment: Negative voters, also tell the reason for -ve voting for my question, I think everything is clear from the question, if you cannot answer the question then also please don't -ve vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sc2WyfB1n6prM9MZQWbb?p=preview)

Modify your directive code as per below

```
 .directive('inputClearNoMaterial', ['$compile','$timeout',function($compile,$timeout){
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {

     var color=attrs.inputClearNoMaterial;
       var style = color ? "color:" + color + ";" : "";

      var template = $compile('<i ng-show="enabled" ng-mousedown="clear()" style="' + style + '" class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>')(scope);
      el.after(template);

      scope.clear = function() {
        ctrl.$setViewValue(null);
        ctrl.$render();
        $timeout(function() {
            el[0].focus();
        }, 0, false);
      };

      el.bind('input focus', function() {
        scope.enabled = !ctrl.$isEmpty(el.val());
        scope.$apply();
      })
      .bind('blur', function() {
        scope.enabled = false;
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
        }]);
```

Comment: in the link provided please check the style.css file also

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is working fine. Can you help me in one thing that If I am showing error message in same line of input box, the error messages fluctuate when cross sign appear and disappears. Is there any way to fix the space of this cross button so that screen wont fluctuate with the cross button? @Balajivaishnav see the plunker-plnkr.co/edit/QYIZZqHS2FJAHF3eIaPj?p=preview –

Comment: please see in full screen of plunker, the space between the input box and error messages fluctuate when cross sign appears and disappears.

Comment: Can you fix the cross sign inside textbox, as now it is changing with the changing width of input box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124374/discussion-between-m-balajivaishnav-and-aanchal).

Comment: @Balaji, I have created one more plunker  where clear icon is present inside the box but the issue is first time when I enter something and click on clear icon, it doesn't show error message- https://plnkr.co/edit/dbhEOylU0WWHKFqotSqG?p=preview

Comment: Can you correct the directive in this new  plunker so that first time also when I clear the text, it should show 'required ' error message